# Fail to build Mono.Addins with the latest Mono 4.3.0 and GTK# on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, mono

Trying to build the latest Monodevelop with latest Mono. I have successfully installed Mono 4.3.0 and GTK#. As I can see, Monodevelop needs Mono.Addins installed, but when I trying to install latest Mono.Addins, it fails with next errors:

```
Mono.Addins.Gui/AddinManagerDialog.cs(189,24): error CS0506: `Mono.Addins.Gui.AddinManagerDialog.Dispose()': cannot override inherited member `GLib.Object.Dispose()' because it is not marked virtual, abstract or override
Mono.Addins.Gui/AddinTreeWidget.cs(52,25): error CS0012: The type `GLib.IIcon' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly `gio-sharp, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f'
Mono.Addins.Gui/ManageSitesDialog.cs(67,24): error CS0506: `Mono.Addins.Gui.ManageSitesDialog.Dispose()': cannot override inherited member `GLib.Object.Dispose()' because it is not marked virtual, abstract or override
Mono.Addins.Gui/NewSiteDialog.cs(46,24): error CS0506: `Mono.Addins.Gui.NewSiteDialog.Dispose()': cannot override inherited member `GLib.Object.Dispose()' because it is not marked virtual, abstract or override
gtk-gui/generated.cs(65,52): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `SizeRequestedArgs' does not exist in the namespace `Gtk'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Mono.Addins.Gui/HeaderBox.cs(98,27): error CS0115: `Mono.Addins.Gui.HeaderBox.OnSizeRequested(ref Gtk.Requisition)' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override
Mono.Addins.Gui/HeaderBox.cs(125,27): error CS0115: `Mono.Addins.Gui.HeaderBox.OnExposeEvent(Gdk.EventExpose)' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override
Mono.Addins.Gui/HoverImageButton.cs(83,44): warning CS0618: `Gtk.Style' is obsolete: `Replaced by StyleContext'
Mono.Addins.Gui/HoverImageButton.cs(150,33): error CS0115: `Mono.Addins.Gui.HoverImageButton.OnExposeEvent(Gdk.EventExpose)' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override
```

How can it be solved?

Ubuntu version - 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. It was simple. I just have chosen wrong version of GTK# library. It should be a `2.12.*` version, but on GTK# master it is `2.99.*`. When I changed the version (by `git checkout`), everything was compiled as it should.

Mono.Addins will compile with `2.99.*` of GTK# only if the flags `--disable-gui` and `--enable-gui-gtk3` is set. In other words, GTK# `2.99.*` will work only with GTK+ 3.0, so Mono.Addins should be configured to use this version of GTK+. Hopefully this explanation will help someone.

Comment: Where can I modify Mono.Addins for GTK# 2.12?